# Простой взлом трафика в частной виртуальной сети

Tags: сеть, взлом, ethernet

У меня на носу курсовая работа по анализу трафика, выявлению аномалий и т.д. Мне необходимо проверить на деле 2 программы по анализу трафика, сравнить их функционал , скорость и качество. Для этого мне нужно создать виртуальную сеть и запустить какой-то "аномальный" процесс для изменения трафика, чтобы это ловил наше ПО. Посоветуйте мне пожалуйста вид взлома и может быть какую-то литературу (ссылки) для успешного проведения практической работы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день) Есть хорошая статья по анализу и перехвату трафика, с последующим взломом, советую к прочтению)
https://codeby.net/threads/pentest-vychislitelnogo-centra-hpc-ataka-na-zaxvat-710-gh-s-moschnostej.70539/

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/435486)

Comment: @Coder подобную статью сложно перенести в ответ. Слишком огромная =/

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik ну офигеть, это прям повод пропускать заведомое нарушение правил с заведомого спам-аккаунта

Comment: @Ипатьев ух. Что откопали то...

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik ну я потом увидел что не совсем прав - это первый пост с данной учетной записи, то есть по нему одному нельзя сказать что это именно спам аккаунт. Но тогда тем более это повод строже следить за правилами - если это ответ-ссылка, то в любом случае ценности для Stack Overflow он не представляет. Тем более что может оказаться спамом